# Powershell script which unistalls extensions in asm

Tags: powershell, azure

I want to try build a powershell script which can uninstall various Extensions (BG info, Microsoft Monitoring agent, VMsnapshot) in multiple subscription, as I am trying to migrate asm to arm I cant move these vm's with the Extensions, as It gives me Error, Can someone explain me in depth how to do this, or post some relevant links here where I can try and build one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following commands to uninstall BG extension.

```
$VM1 = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName “cloudservice” -Name “vmname”
Set-AzureVMBGInfoExtension -VM $VM1 –Uninstall -ReferenceName “BGInfo” | Update-AzureVM
```

Use the following commands to uninstall Microsoft Monitoring agent.

```
$VM1 = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName “cloudservice” -Name “vmname”
Set-AzureVMExtension -VM $VM1 –Uninstall -ReferenceName “Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring.MicrosoftMonitoringAgent” -ExtensionName “MicrosoftMonitoringAgent” -Publisher “Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring” -Version “1.*” | Update-AzureVM
```

Use the following commands to uninstall VMsnapshot.

```
$VM1 = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName “cloudservice” -Name “vmname”
Set-AzureVMExtension -VM $VM1 –Uninstall -ReferenceName “VMSnapshot” -ExtensionName “VMSnapshot” -Publisher “Microsoft.Azure.RecoveryServices” -Version “1.0” | Update-AzureVM
```

The [blog](http://www.itgeekrambling.co.uk/azure-migrating-asm-to-arm-removing-extensions/) will be helpful.

Comment: thats the samE blog which I am following..thanks for the response.

Comment: I have a question How can I remove all the extensions from a virtual machine, I found this command but its not doing what it suppose to do

$service = "testrunning"
$vmname = "testrunning"

$VM1 = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $service -Name $vmname
Remove-AzureVMExtension -VM $VM1 -RemoveAll | Update-AzureVM

Comment: I want to simply remove all the extensions from a vm in a cloud service above command wont delete all the extensions

Comment: If not possible then How can I find this command in there documentation 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure/remove-azurevmextension?view=azuresmps-4.0.0

Comment: `Remove-​Azure​VM​Extension` does not work for `BG info, Microsoft Monitoring agent, VMsnapshot` the three extension, you need enable or remove them with specific commands.

Comment: why that documentation stats that it Can remove all the extensions in a VM

Comment: I get the same result with you, I also don't know why, you should use specific commands to remove specific extensions. I will give a feedback to Azure.

Comment: No, I suggest you could use `Set-AzureVMBGInfoExtension -VM $VM1 –Uninstall -ReferenceName “BGInfo” | Update-AzureVM` to uninstall your extensions.

Comment: @TheMan You also give feedback like this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/257).

Comment: I opend a new issue in thE link which you gave me. 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/4174